# What is the path for the command cf in una warden linux?

Tags: command-line-interface, cloud-foundry, warden

I would like execute shell commands to run Cloud foundry shell commands.

Example:

```
cf apps
```

Where is the path in a warden linux the command cf?

My idea is to call cf command from PHP or Node. 
Idea:

```
<?php
exec("cf apps 2>&1", $output);
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Juan Antonio

Answer (score 0):

You will specified your operating system, the following package for redhat/centos 64 bit.

For **cf** command, download the package and install rpm.

http://go-cli.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/releases/v6.12.2/cf-cli_amd64.rpm

```
# cf --version

cf version 6.12.2-24abed3-2015-07-15T21:21:01+00:00
```

also refer the url :

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/warden

Comment: Hi for Ubuntu, exist a repository. [https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/#!topic/vcap-dev/lVbySeabb_8]( https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/#!topic/vcap-dev/lVbySeabb_8)

Comment: Yes, but my question is about how to execute a cf command from a application deployed in cloud foundry, not in the linux system where I installed cloud foundry. How to exec in a PHP or another scripting languaje some similar to: <?php
$output = shell_exec('cf apps');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>